# Postfix stopped working: connection refused

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta

I have been using postfix on an ec2 ubuntu instance to send out emails to all of our clients. All has worked fine until today, when i tried to send out 50 emails.

None of them got sent, and when checking the queue all of them have 'delivery temporarily suspended' and 'Connection timed out'

I also noticed that when I try and restart postfix, I now get a set of warnings:

```
postfix: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 35: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=ip-172-31-47-141.eu-west-1.compute.internal
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 35: overriding earlier entry: myhostname=ip ADDRESS .eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

It has been absolutly fine until today

Answer (score 0):

Amazon AWS rate-limits the amount of SMTP traffic that you can send.  You have to request these limits to be removed:

https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request